# Retrieve stuck ether on smart contract

Tags: ether, tokens, wallet-transfer

Is there any way to recover ether that is stuck in a smart contract? 
refundMoney() method was supposed to call only after everything is finalized but because someone has transferred some ether amount from an exchange wallet and we had to refund that. Now the weiRaised variable is showing more value than the smart contract currently have.

Here is the live contract deployed with source code
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7ff0b2afa427507a50ed4f82231b2b8a972fdff1

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Ownable {
  address public owner;
  event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
  constructor() public { owner = msg.sender;  }

  modifier onlyOwner() {     
      address sender =  msg.sender;
      address _owner = owner;
      require(msg.sender == _owner);    
      _;  
  }

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public { 
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
  }
}

library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

contract ERC20Basic {
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) public constant returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

/**
 * @title ERC20 interface
 * @dev see https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 */
contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public constant returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;
  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  /**
  * @dev transfer token for a specified address
  * @param _to The address to transfer to.
  * @param _value The amount to be transferred.
  */
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));

    // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
  * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
  * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
  * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
  */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public constant returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}

/**
 * @title Standard ERC20 token
 *
 * @dev Implementation of the basic standard token.
 * @dev https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20
 * @dev Based on code by FirstBlood: https://github.com/Firstbloodio/token/blob/master/smart_contract/FirstBloodToken.sol
 */
contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;

  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    uint256 _allowance = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = _allowance.sub(_value);
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   *
   * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
   * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
   * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public constant returns (uint256 remaining) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  /**
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   */
  function increaseApproval (address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool success) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  function decreaseApproval (address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool success) {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

}

contract MintableToken is StandardToken, Ownable {
  event Mint(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
  event MintFinished();

  bool public mintingFinished = false;

  modifier canMint() {
    require(!mintingFinished);
    _;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to mint tokens
   * @param _to The address that will receive the minted tokens.
   * @param _amount The amount of tokens to mint.
   * @return A boolean that indicates if the operation was successful.
   */
  function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner canMint public returns (bool) {
    totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_amount);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
    emit Mint(_to, _amount);
    emit Transfer(0x0, _to, _amount);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to mint tokens
   * @param _to The address that will receive the minted tokens.
   * @param _amount The amount of tokens to mint.
   * @return A boolean that indicates if the operation was successful.
   */
  function mintFinalize(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyOwner canMint public returns (bool) {
    totalSupply = totalSupply.add(_amount);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
    emit Mint(_to, _amount);
    emit Transfer(0x0, _to, _amount);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to stop minting new tokens.
   * @return True if the operation was successful.
   */
  function finishMinting() onlyOwner public returns (bool) {
    mintingFinished = true;
    emit MintFinished();
    return true;
  }
}

/**
 * @title SwordToken
 * @dev Sword ERC20 Token that can be minted.
 * It is meant to be used in Sword crowdsale contract.
 */
contract SwordToken is MintableToken {

    string public constant name = "Sword Coin"; 
    string public constant symbol = "SWDC";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;

    function getTotalSupply() view public returns (uint256) {
        return totalSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        super.transfer(_to, _value);
    }

}

contract KycContractInterface {
    function isAddressVerified(address _address) public view returns (bool);
}

contract KycContract is Ownable {

    mapping (address => bool) verifiedAddresses;

    function isAddressVerified(address _address) public view returns (bool) {
        return verifiedAddresses[_address];
    }

    function addAddress(address _newAddress) public onlyOwner {
        require(!verifiedAddresses[_newAddress]);

        verifiedAddresses[_newAddress] = true;
    }

    function removeAddress(address _oldAddress) public onlyOwner {
        require(verifiedAddresses[_oldAddress]);

        verifiedAddresses[_oldAddress] = false;
    }

    function batchAddAddresses(address[] _addresses) public onlyOwner {
        for (uint cnt = 0; cnt < _addresses.length; cnt++) {
            assert(!verifiedAddresses[_addresses[cnt]]);
            verifiedAddresses[_addresses[cnt]] = true;
        }
    }
}


/**
 * @title SwordCrowdsale
 * @dev This is Sword's crowdsale contract.
 */
contract SwordCrowdsale is Ownable {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    // start and end timestamps where investments are allowed (both inclusive)
    uint256 public startTime;
    uint256 public endTime;
    // amount of raised money in wei
    uint256 public weiRaised;
    uint256 public limitDateSale; // end date in units

    bool public isSoftCapHit = false;
    bool public isStarted = false;
    bool public isFinalized = false;

   struct ContributorData {
        uint256 contributionAmount;
        uint256 tokensIssued;
    }

   address[] public tokenSendFailures;

    mapping(address => ContributorData) public contributorList;
    mapping(uint => address) contributorIndexes;
    uint nextContributorIndex;

    constructor() public {}

   function init(uint256 _totalTokens, uint256 _tokensForCrowdsale, address _wallet, 
        uint256 _etherInUSD, address _tokenAddress, uint256 _softCapInEthers, uint256 _hardCapInEthers, 
        uint _saleDurationInDays, address _kycAddress, uint bonus) onlyOwner public {

        setTotalTokens(_totalTokens);
        setTokensForCrowdSale(_tokensForCrowdsale);
        setWallet(_wallet);
        setRate(_etherInUSD);
        setTokenAddress(_tokenAddress);
        setSoftCap(_softCapInEthers);
        setHardCap(_hardCapInEthers);
        setSaleDuration(_saleDurationInDays);
        setKycAddress(_kycAddress);
        setSaleBonus(bonus);
        kyc = KycContract(_kycAddress);
        start(); // starting the crowdsale
   }

    /**
    * @dev Must be called to start the crowdsale
    */
    function start() onlyOwner public {
        require(!isStarted);
        require(!hasStarted());
        require(wallet != address(0));
        require(tokenAddress != address(0));
        require(kycAddress != address(0));
        require(rate != 0);
        require(saleDuration != 0);
        require(totalTokens != 0);
        require(tokensForCrowdSale != 0);
        require(softCap != 0);
        require(hardCap != 0);

        starting();
        emit SwordStarted();

        isStarted = true;
    }


   uint256 public totalTokens = 0;
   function setTotalTokens(uint256 _totalTokens) onlyOwner public {
       totalTokens = _totalTokens * (10 ** 18); // Total 1 billion tokens, 75 percent will be sold
   }

   uint256 public tokensForCrowdSale = 0;
   function setTokensForCrowdSale(uint256 _tokensForCrowdsale) onlyOwner public {
       tokensForCrowdSale = _tokensForCrowdsale * (10 ** 18); // Total 1 billion tokens, 75 percent will be sold 
   }

    // address where funds are collected
    address public wallet = 0x0;
    function setWallet(address _wallet) onlyOwner public {
        wallet = _wallet;
    } 

    uint256 public rate = 0;
    function setRate(uint256 _etherInUSD) public onlyOwner{
         rate = (5 * (10**18) / 100) / _etherInUSD;
    }

    // The token being sold
    SwordToken public token;
    address tokenAddress = 0x0; 
    function setTokenAddress(address _tokenAddress) public onlyOwner {
        tokenAddress = _tokenAddress; // to check if token address is provided at start
        token = SwordToken(_tokenAddress);
    }

   uint256 public softCap = 0;
   function setSoftCap(uint256 _softCap) onlyOwner public {
       softCap = _softCap * (10 ** 18); 
    }

   uint256 public hardCap = 0; 
   function setHardCap(uint256 _hardCap) onlyOwner public {
       hardCap = _hardCap * (10 ** 18); 
   }

    // sale period (includes holidays)
    uint public saleDuration = 0; // in days ex: 60.
    function setSaleDuration(uint _saleDurationInDays) onlyOwner public {
        saleDuration = _saleDurationInDays;
        limitDateSale = startTime + (saleDuration * 1 days);
        endTime = limitDateSale;
    }

    address kycAddress = 0x0;
    function setKycAddress(address _kycAddress) onlyOwner public {
        kycAddress = _kycAddress;
    }

    uint public saleBonus = 0; // ex. 10
    function setSaleBonus(uint bonus) public onlyOwner{
        saleBonus = bonus;
    }

   bool public isKYCRequiredToReceiveFunds = true; // whether Kyc is required to receive funds.
    function setKYCRequiredToReceiveFunds(bool IS_KYCRequiredToReceiveFunds) public onlyOwner{
        isKYCRequiredToReceiveFunds = IS_KYCRequiredToReceiveFunds;
    }

    bool public isKYCRequiredToSendTokens = true; // whether Kyc is required to send tokens.
      function setKYCRequiredToSendTokens(bool IS_KYCRequiredToSendTokens) public onlyOwner{
        isKYCRequiredToSendTokens = IS_KYCRequiredToSendTokens;
    }


    // fallback function can be used to buy tokens
    function () public payable {
        buyTokens(msg.sender);
    }

   KycContract public kyc;
   function transferKycOwnerShip(address _address) onlyOwner public {
       kyc.transferOwnership(_address);
   }

   function transferTokenOwnership(address _address) onlyOwner public {
       token.transferOwnership(_address);
   }

    /**
     * release Tokens
     */
    function releaseAllTokens() onlyOwner public {
        for(uint i=0; i < nextContributorIndex; i++) {
            address addressToSendTo = contributorIndexes[i]; // address of user
            releaseTokens(addressToSendTo);
        }
    }

    /**
     * release Tokens of an individual address
     */
    function releaseTokens(address _contributerAddress) onlyOwner public {
        if(isKYCRequiredToSendTokens){
             if(KycContractInterface(kycAddress).isAddressVerified(_contributerAddress)){ // if kyc needs to be checked at release time
                release(_contributerAddress);
             }
        } else {
            release(_contributerAddress);
        }
    }

    function release(address _contributerAddress) internal {
        if(contributorList[_contributerAddress].tokensIssued > 0) { 
            if(token.mint(_contributerAddress, contributorList[_contributerAddress].tokensIssued)) { // tokens sent successfully
                contributorList[_contributerAddress].tokensIssued = 0;
                contributorList[_contributerAddress].contributionAmount = 0;
            } else { // token sending failed, has to be processed manually
                tokenSendFailures.push(_contributerAddress);
            }
        }
    }

    function tokenSendFailuresCount() public view returns (uint) {
        return tokenSendFailures.length;
    }

    function buyTokens(address beneficiary) public payable {
        require(beneficiary != address(0));
        require(validPurchase());
        if(isKYCRequiredToReceiveFunds){
            require(KycContractInterface(kycAddress).isAddressVerified(msg.sender));
        }

        uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;

        // calculate token amount to be created
        uint256 tokens = computeTokens(weiAmount);

        require(isWithinTokenAllocLimit(tokens));

        // update state - Add to eth raised
        weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);

        if (contributorList[beneficiary].contributionAmount == 0) { // if its a new contributor, add him and increase index
            contributorIndexes[nextContributorIndex] = beneficiary;
            nextContributorIndex += 1;
        }
        contributorList[beneficiary].contributionAmount += weiAmount;
        contributorList[beneficiary].tokensIssued += tokens;

        emit SwordTokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);
        handleFunds();
    }

      /**
    * event for token purchase logging
    * @param purchaser who paid for the tokens
    * @param beneficiary who got the tokens
    * @param value weis paid for purchase
    * @param amount amount of tokens purchased
    */
    event SwordTokenPurchase(address indexed purchaser, address indexed beneficiary, uint256 value, uint256 amount);

    function investorCount() constant public returns(uint) {
        return nextContributorIndex;
    }

    // @return true if crowdsale event has started
    function hasStarted() public constant returns (bool) {
        return (startTime != 0 && now > startTime);
    }

    // send ether to the fund collection wallet
    function forwardFunds() internal {
        wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    }

     // send ether to the fund collection wallet
    function forwardAllRaisedFunds() internal {
        wallet.transfer(weiRaised);
    }

    function isWithinSaleTimeLimit() internal view returns (bool) {
        return now <= limitDateSale;
    }

    function isWithinSaleLimit(uint256 _tokens) internal view returns (bool) {
        return token.getTotalSupply().add(_tokens) <= tokensForCrowdSale;
    }

    function computeTokens(uint256 weiAmount) view internal returns (uint256) {
        uint256 appliedBonus = 0;
        if (isWithinSaleTimeLimit()) {
            appliedBonus = saleBonus;
        } 
        return (weiAmount.div(rate) + (weiAmount.div(rate).mul(appliedBonus).div(100))) * (10 ** 18);
    }

    function isWithinTokenAllocLimit(uint256 _tokens) view internal returns (bool) {
        return (isWithinSaleTimeLimit() && isWithinSaleLimit(_tokens));
    }

    function didSoftCapReached() internal returns (bool) {
        if(weiRaised >= softCap){
            isSoftCapHit = true; // setting the flag that soft cap is hit and all funds should be sent directly to wallet from now on.
        } else {
            isSoftCapHit = false;
        }
        return isSoftCapHit;
    }

    // overriding SwordBaseCrowdsale#validPurchase to add extra cap logic
    // @return true if investors can buy at the moment
    function validPurchase() internal constant returns (bool) {
        bool withinCap = weiRaised.add(msg.value) <= hardCap;
        bool withinPeriod = now >= startTime && now <= endTime; 
        bool nonZeroPurchase = msg.value != 0; 
        return (withinPeriod && nonZeroPurchase) && withinCap && isWithinSaleTimeLimit();
    }

    // overriding Crowdsale#hasEnded to add cap logic
    // @return true if crowdsale event has ended
    function hasEnded() public constant returns (bool) {
        bool capReached = weiRaised >= hardCap;
        return (endTime != 0 && now > endTime) || capReached;
    }



  event SwordStarted();
  event SwordFinalized();

  /**
   * @dev Must be called after crowdsale ends, to do some extra finalization
   * work. Calls the contract's finalization function.
   */
  function finalize() onlyOwner public {
    require(!isFinalized);
   // require(hasEnded());

    finalization();
    emit SwordFinalized();

    isFinalized = true;
  }

    function starting() internal {
        startTime = now;
        limitDateSale = startTime + (saleDuration * 1 days);
        endTime = limitDateSale;
    }

    function finalization() internal {
        uint256 remainingTokens = totalTokens.sub(token.getTotalSupply());
        token.mintFinalize(wallet, remainingTokens);
        forwardAllRaisedFunds(); 
    }

    // overridden
    function handleFunds() internal {
        if(isSoftCapHit){ // if soft cap is reached, start transferring funds immediately to wallet
            forwardFunds();  
        } else {
            if(didSoftCapReached()){    
                forwardAllRaisedFunds();            
            }
        }
    }

     modifier afterDeadline() { if (hasEnded() || isFinalized) _; } // a modifier to tell token sale ended 

  /**
     * auto refund Tokens
     */
    function refundAllMoney() onlyOwner public {
        for(uint i=0; i < nextContributorIndex; i++) {
            address addressToSendTo = contributorIndexes[i];
            refundMoney(addressToSendTo); 
        }
    }

    /**
     * refund Tokens of a single address
     */
    function refundMoney(address _address) onlyOwner public {
        uint amount = contributorList[_address].contributionAmount;
        if (amount > 0 && _address.send(amount)) { // user got money back
            contributorList[_address].contributionAmount =  0;
            contributorList[_address].tokensIssued =  0;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by Thomas and Raghav your problem is in the method `forwardAllRaisedFunds` that uses `weiRaised` to transfer funds out of your contract, if that variable has a value larger than available the transfer will fail.

There is a trick to increment the balance of a contract without executing the fallback function.

If you `selfdestruct` a dummy contract and put your contract as target. It will increment the balance keeping the variable `weiRaised` unchanged.

Comment: Can you explain why that works without executing the fallback function?

Comment: Amazing answer. Very cool.

Comment: @RaghavSood It is how `selfdestruct` work, it is documented in [solidity security considerations](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#sending-and-receiving-ether), an other places [Know attacks](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/).

Answer (score 1):

Unless you built the capability into the code to upgrade your way out of the problem or in some way you anticipated the problem and built a fail-safe, you're probably out of luck. Outside chance that there's a second bug that would allow you to exploit the contract and somehow extract the ether that way (again, unlikely). There's no process to roll back the state of a contract other than a hard fork containing what is called an irregular state change. Getting one of those to happen is (I hope) impossible. That's the nature of the immutable code.

Answer (score 1):

[cross posted from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51848581/retrieve-stuck-ether-on-smart-contract/51851041#51851041)

It appears that your `refundMoney()` implementation has a bug, and doesn't decrease the `weiRaised` value. This means that once you issue a refund, you can no longer use `forwardAllRaisedFunds()` to drain the contract.

The somewhat good news (for the person who asked for the refund) is that this isn't their fault. Your bug would be triggered even in the regular course of action after you hit the softcap, since funds after the softcap are forwarded automatically, but are still added to `weiRaised`. There is no scenario in which you would have been able to access all the funds, unless you did not issue a refund *and* raised less money than the softcap.

The ether in this contract is effectively stuck. You will still be able to receive any funds after the softcap is hit, but funds under the softcap can never be retrieved.